# How can I install closet doors for a very long closet opening?

Tags: doors, closet

I have a very long closet opening (about 120" wide and 80" tall) and I'm struggling to find a set of doors for it. Any suggestions for how to add doors to such a long closet opening?

All I can find is closet doors for smaller openings or custom-ordering doors (but those are $$$$).

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Normally I'd have set this up as a dual 5 ft. opening, for which you can easily find either bypass or bi-fold door kits. Are you open to posting the center?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you make the doors yourself out of 3/4" birch veneer lumber core plywood. Using a conventional double track system for sliding doors you can install three doors, one on the front track and two on the back track. The front sliding door was normally kept in the center position but could be pushed left or right *(you pick which choice is suitable for your application)* to access the center portion of the closet.

For sliding doors like this it is typical to have the doors overlap some so that floor guides will stay engaged with the doors. In an application like this you install two sets of floor guides and then install a stop on the front track to restrict the slide range of the center door to be left or right only.

For a 120" opening to allow for about 2" door overlap each door would be about 42" wide. This can be easily cut from a 48" x 96" sheet of the lumber core plywood. You would need three sheets total.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your own bi-fold doors using 30" door leaves or bypass doors using 32" door leaves. You may need to cut the doors if the door opening is only 80" tall. There may be a problem with that, most doors will only let you cut 1" off any side, top or bottom before you get into the core of the door.....Not good... If you are having trouble finding something off the shelf, you need to assemble what you need using the same parts the the ready made ones use. You should use a heavier gauge hardware for it, since there will be more door "hanging out there" than the smaller door arrangements. This is referring to bi-fold doors, by pass doors will not have that issue since all doors are hung from a track.

If you want a kinda bi-fold door and your finished opening is very square, level at the head and plumb on the sides, you can set the first 2 door leaves on either side of the closet opening like any other hinged door, 3 hinges on each, door stop on the jamb head and sides. The screws will need to be long enough to go into the framing on this one. once those leaves are in place and acting proper, hold them in place with magnetic catches at the top. This all done should give you a 5' opening to deal with. With the same hinges that are used on the other panels already in place, set 3 more on each panel on either side. You will need to get the sizes right or trouble will occur while operating the doors. This is, just to mention some that should not be done by a first timer. If you can do it it will work. When it is all finished yo have the capacity to open up a 5 ft wide door on either side and fold it back on itself. Magnetic catches will be needed at these panels too.

Not the best way to work it, but if your jamb is predefined in its' sizes, it at least an option to consider. If you opening was 82" +/- your options for by pass or bi-fold hardware would be simpler.